# How to use output of system() function as a string in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm currently programming a package manager for Android using C and GCC as my compiler. In order to  install packages I've made a function that hooks into an API for the f-droid main repository. It does this through using system() to call GET and grep to grab the version number from the resulting string. I need to find a way to use the output of system() (which has been modified by grep) as a string. I have no idea how to do this in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void syncapk(char * apkname);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc==1) {
        printf("Displaying help screen.\n");
    } else if(argc>=2) {
        if(strncmp(argv[1], "sync\n", 4) == 0) {
            if(argc==3) {
                syncapk(argv[2]);
            } else {
                printf("No package specified!\n");
            }
        } else if(strncmp(argv[1], "upgrade", 7) == 0) { 
            printf("Upgrading all packages.\n");
        } else if(strncmp(argv[1], "remove", 6) == 0) { 
            printf("Removing package.\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void syncapk(char * apkname) {
    printf("Syncing package: %s!\n", apkname);
    char apkversion[100];
    sprintf(apkversion, "GET https://f-droid.org/api/v1/packages/%s HTTP/1.1 | grep -oP '(?<=suggestedVersionCode\":).*(?=,\"packages)'", apkname);
    system(apkversion);
    char synccmd[100];
    sprintf(synccmd, "wget https://f-droid.org/repo/%s_%s.apk", apkname, apkversion);
    system(synccmd);
}
```

Comment: `system()` returns an `int`, not a string. Perhaps use `popen()` instead?

Comment: How would I go about using popen() with all those arguments and the pipe mentioned in sprintf()?

Comment: Note that you might be better served using the POSIX regular expression functions instead of invoking `grep`, an external utility. The latter means you must take care to make sure `grep` is in `$PATH` and generally complicates your code. EDIT: likewise, you should seriously consider a library like libcurl instead of invoking `wget` if this is for any serious usage.

Comment: `sprintf` is dangerous, and the sizes of your buffers (100) are arbitrary. Use `snprintf` or `fprintf` with `open_memstream` (or use `asprintf`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to successfully make this program work. I did end up using libcurl and it is not ideal to use regular expressions to grab JSON info: it is much better to parse it with a library like cjson (which I ended up doing).